# Need help troubleshooting virtual host

Tags: apache2, mysql, database

Good day,
  I maintain system for a non-profit and I'm having difficulty with one of our virtual hosts.  I'm stumped as to where the issue is.

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it's reasonably current on updates, but there are some waiting to apply, but I don't want to update anything until I positively figure out what is wrong.

The server hosts 5 virtual hosts, 4 of them are functioning fine running the LAMP stack and hosting Wordpress sites.  One such site is we.ifma.org.

The site in question is awards.ifma.org and is returning a database connection error.  I do not think it is a wordpress error.  I cannot load a test info.php file off of this host.  I can load license.txt, but test .htm and .html files fail.

/var/log/, /var/log/mysql/ /var/log/apache are not showing any issues.

I originally set this server up a couple of years ago and then transitioned it to a junior developer who worked for us.  He left a couple of months ago and I was asked to get this site back up and running.  I know he installed puppet, but I do not know anything about his config of it and I have not had time to dig into it.

We also run new-relic for monitoring and there are no errors coming from this server.

What I need help with is figuring out how to troubleshoot why this virtual host is giving me an error.  I think it is a PHP or apache error.  I did run aptitude and look at the installed packages and I don't see phpmyadmin.  That doesn't mean it's not hiding somewhere... it's just not there as 'phpmyadmin.'

Comment: I did some more digging and can get a HTML file to load.... but not a php file.  trying to load info.php results in a database error message.

Comment: Are the packages `php5 libapache2-mod-php5` installed?

Comment: Yes..... there are 4 other identical virtual hosts on the server that run with no problems.... it's just this one host that has died.

Comment: What is the database connection error that is returned?  And why am I able to display the page for awards.ifma.org?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not about virtual host configuration, because the site is loading a page.

Also, it's not a php problem, otherwise any of the server sites would not be running.

Verify the file wp-config.php for wordpress in site having connection problem.

You also can try a command line connection to database, using root authentication credentials:

$ mysql -u root -p

[MySQL command line connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXsch.png)

[MySQL connection successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLXK8.png)

If connection fails, a error message will be shown